# [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "INTO" for INSERT into CSV file

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, amazon-redshift

I try to output everything from temp table to csv on local drive in SQL Workbench (Redshift Amazon Server)

```
SELECT *
FROM #IDTable
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Users\\MYAN\\Documents\\out.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Then I run into error message as follows:

> Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "INTO" 
>   Position: 24;

Could anyone help with it? Thank you!!

Comment: You must use UNLOAD command.The above will not work in redshift

Comment: are you really using mysql-workbench? please check and update your tags if necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do like this on Amazon-Redshift, either you have to use 'S3' or any 'EC-2' instance to output your select query.

The unload syntax would go like this.

```
 UNLOAD ('select-statement') TO 's3://object-path/name-prefix' authorization [ option [ ... ] ]
```

Refer Redshif documents online here.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html